# how to monitor changes in file without cron job in AIX

Tags: python, shell, cron, scheduled-tasks, aix

I am trying to monitor a file and if there is a change file I need to execute a script but the catch is **cron job** is not allowed, also this will be executed on AIX system.

Can somebody help me here on how to proceed.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the the solution :

```
#!/bin/ksh
for file in /home/*
do
    sum1="$(csum -h MD5 1.txt)"
    echo "$sum1"
    sleep 100
    sum2="$(csum -h MD5 1.txt)"
    echo "$sum2"
    if [ "$sum1" == "$sum2" ];
    then
       echo "Identical"
    else
       echo "Different"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to write a daemon (another script perhaps) and keep checking the file for changes.

It is possible to write a script with infinite loop and the loop can contain the file check logic.